# Warning in GCP Cloud SQL Database

Tags: google-cloud-platform, warnings, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-logging

Some time ago a warning showed up in loggings, as long as I can see it does not affect the projects workflow but it mess the logs.
The warning is:

```
[Warning] User 'mysql.session'@'localhost' was assigned access 0x8000 but was allowed to have only 0x0.
```

What is it about?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m gonna list the most common root causes for that error message you are getting:

1. Permissions: There are user permissions for the database, cloud functions, and the IAM roles. You can make it work by giving "All User" complete access. This is not secure, of course, but works.
2. Prod vs Dev (emulator): You can recall that access is less strict within the Google ecosystem, so running your functions on your emulator was a bad idea for troubleshooting. There are other ways (such as SSL or VM). As a last scenario, maybe you will have to deploy every time.
3. ORM: If you are using TypeORM for the first time, you will see that many of the tutorials are outdated.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Im going to check them!

Comment: Can I help you with other information? If you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the check mark (✔️) on the left side under the vote arrows. Should change the color to green.